# ngFor TrackbyFunction support ng-template with ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular

```
<div *ngFor="let item of sourcelist; trackBy: TrackbyFunction" (click)="clickHandler(item)">
   <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{item:item}">
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Above code, every time I set sourcelist, all the template will be generate again, even I have set trackBy,
also I tried this https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf sample,

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ng-template>
```

but it does not support ngTemplateOutlet, I need ngTemplateOutlet to get templte outside this component.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: Could you provide the code of your track by function ?